# jQuery alternative equal to "firstChild.nodeValue"

Tags: jquery

I've been struggling to find a jQuery alternative that does exactly the same as:

```
document.getElementById("element").firstChild.nodeValue = value;
```

Here's the relevant html structure:

```
<div id="clock">
    <div id="day">
    </div>
    <div id="date">
    </div>
</div>
```

For "day" and "date" I can just use `$("#day").text(day)` and `$("#date").text(date)` but as soon as I use `$("#clock").text(clock)` for "clock", the "day" and "date" disappear and only the "clock" element is shown.

Of course, "clock" is a parent element of the other two so maybe it 'overrides' the children elements if I use the jQuery code. Strangely, using pseudo elements like `:first-child` or `:first` doesn't help.

Happy to hear a solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to insert some text before the `#day` element.

```
$("#clock").prepend('your text');
```

or

```
$("#day").before('your text');
```

should do it.

---

Note that `.firstChild.nodeValue = value;` only inserts new text before the element because you have a text node there, containing only white spaces. If your HTML was

```
<div id="clock"><div id="day"></div></div>
```

it wouldn't do anything, because `.firstChild` would refer to `#day` and `nodeValue` is not defined for element nodes.

Comment: I see.. the idea of using some sort of 'before' function totally slipped my mind. I tested it and it's working. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set value for the first-child of "clock" Div you have to do :

```
$("#clock :first").text("Your Content");
```